# Trying to create a navbar with custom button shapes and centered buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make the navebar for a community site and I am having trouble getting the navbar to both look corect and function properly. I can't seem to get the brand and buttons to center and I can't get the shape of the buttons to work correctly. I'm still very new to bootstrap and have no clue what to do.

I am trying to mimic this concept: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNkHt.jpg

The header logo and buton images are all here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g89xn.jpg

This is what I have so far for HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-targer="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="assets/Header_Logo.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="homeButton"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="articleButton"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="builderButton"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="guideButton"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="aboutButton"><a href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and CSS

```
body{
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/8M7YsDs.jpg");
    background-position: center;
}

.navbar{
    height: 140px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("../assets/Header/Header.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-position: center;
    border: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}


.navbar-nav{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.homeButton{
    background-image: url("../assets/Header/Home_Button.png");
    height: 32px;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

.articleButton{
    background-image: url("../assets/Header/Articles_Button.png");
    height: 32px;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

.builderButton{
    background-image: url("../assets/Header/Builder_Button.png");
    height: 32px;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

.guideButton{
    background-image: url("../assets/Header/Guides_Button.png");
    height: 32px;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

.aboutButton{
    background-image: url("../assets/Header/About_Button.png");
    height: 32px;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you very much.

Edit: Looks like I may have made some progress though the problem is not solved

Comment: Is your site responsive?

Comment: No this is the framework for the site that will display the list of guides

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WRvPBO

Comment: Wait sorry I'm wrong. The site is responsive. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ummm....is the demo site in the pictures provided responsive? Because the background images make it very hard to make it responsive. Adaptive would be more realistic